# How do you render a partial to a relation in Rails 4.0.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This was working in Rails 4.0.0, now since upgrading last week it is displaying nothing.

Here is the HAML `posts/_post.haml`

```
=post.id
=post.tags
=post.tags.length
=render post.tags
```

The output, with `render` displaying nothing!

> `113 #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Tag:0x12388c08> 0`

This shows the `post.tags.length` as 0. However, the post DOES have tags! They ALL do!

```
irb(main):168:0> p.id
=> 113
irb(main):169:0> p.tags.length
=> 2
```

So why isn't the partial rendering in the view? I have other partials inside partials which render.

When I go to `post/show.haml`, it displays the tags just fine.

```
=@post.tags
=@post.tags.length
=render @post.tags
```

> `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Tag:0xc24f9c0> 2  FINANCE  BUSINESS`

Not sure if it matters, this is the only thing different with this relation than the others. Here is the `post` model.

```
has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if you do `render post.tags.load`?

Comment: @PaulRichter No, `=post.tags.load.length` spits out 0.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106143/how-do-i-keep-has-many-through-relationships-when-serializing-to-json-and-back

Answer (score 0):

```
=post.tags.length
```

is `returning 0` that means there are no tags associated with the given post.

I would suggest to add the following line in your `posts/_post.haml`

```
= post.id
```

Running your code should give you `id` of the current post.
Then run `rails dbconsole` to verify whether or not the given post id has any associated tags.

Comment: There are tags associated with the post. I updated with the post.id.