# How do I keep has_many :through relationships when serializing to JSON and back in Rails 4.0.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, redis

How do I convert to JSON and back and keep the relationships? It thinks they don't exist when I un-parcel the object!

```
irb(main):106:0* p = Post.last
=> #<Post ...
irb(main):107:0> p.tags
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Tag id: 41, ...
irb(main):109:0* p.tags.count
=> 2                               #### !!!!!!!!!!!!

irb(main):110:0> json = p.to_json
=> "{\"id\":113,\"title\":... }"
irb(main):111:0> p2 = Post.new( JSON.parse(json) )
=> #<Post id: 113, title: ... 

irb(main):112:0> p2.tags
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
irb(main):113:0> p2.tags.count
=> 0                               #### !!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Here is the model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
```

What someone suggested, but doesn't work

```
irb(main):206:0* Post.new.from_json p.to_json(include: :tags)
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Tag(#60747984) expected, got Hash(#15487524)
```

Comment: you call `p2 = Post.new( JSON.parse(json) )` this not save to db. And call `p2.tags.count` query on your db but you not save data.

Comment: @Monk_Code No that still doesn't work. See comment on answer below also. `> p2 = Post.new( JSON.parse(json) )`
`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Tag(#62190408) expected, got Hash(#15487524)`

Answer (score 3):

I simulated the exact same scenario like yours and found out:

Whenever a model(Post) has a `has_many through` association then upon creating an instance of that Model i.e., `Post` passing a `Hash` for eg: `Post.new( JSON.parse(json) )` or `Post.new(id: 113)` seems like Rails treats them differently although they are pointing to the same record.

I ran the following commands in the sequence as given below:

```
p = Post.last
p.tags
p.tags.count
json = p.to_json

p2 = Post.new( JSON.parse(json) )
p2.tags
p2.tags.count   ## Gives incorrect count

p3 = Post.find(JSON.parse(json)["id"])    ### See notes below
p3.tags
p3.tags.count   ## Gives the correct count
```

Instead of creating a new instance of Post using Hash directly, I fetched the record from database using the `id` obtained from deserializing json. In this case, the instance `p3` and instance `p2` refer to the same Post but Rails is interpreting them differently.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm actually serializing and de-serializing them into a Redis cache to speed it up. I was hoping to avoid the DB. Perhaps it is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

***Disclaimer:** This is not, in any way, an ideal solution (and I would call it down-right cheesy), but its about the only thing I've been able to come up with for your scenario.*

What Kirti Thorat said is correct; when you have a dependent object, Rails expects the association in the hash to be of that specific class (in your case, a `Tag` object). Hence the error you're getting: `Tag expected...got Hash`.

**Here comes the cheesy part:** One way to properly deserialize a complex object is to leverage the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method. By using this method, you'll allow your `Post` class to properly deserialize the dependent `Tag` key-value pairs to proper `Tag` objects. Start with this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
    # rest of class
end
```

Since `accepts_nested_attributes_for` searches for a key with the word `_attributes` for the given association, you'll have to alter the JSON when it is rendered to accommodate this by overriding the `as_json` method in your `Post` class, like so:

```
def as_json(options={})
  json_hash = super.as_json(options)

  unless json_hash["tags"].nil?
    json_hash["tags_attributes"] = json_hash["tags"] # Renaming the key
    json_hash.delete("tags") # remove the now unnecessary "tags" key
  end

  json_hash # don't forget to return this at the end
end
```

*Side note: There are lots of json building gems such as [`acts_as_api`](https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api) that will allow you to remove this `as_json` overriding business*

So now your rendered JSON has all the `Post` attributes, plus an array of `tag` attribute key-value pairs under the key `tags_attributes`.

Technically speaking, if you were to deserialize this rendered JSON in the manner suggested by Kirti, it would work and you would get back a properly populated active record object. **However**, unfortunately, the presence of the `id` attributes in both the parent `Post` object, and the dependent `tag` objects means that active record will fire off at least one SQL query. It will do a quick lookup for the tags to determine if anything needs to be added or deleted, as per the specifications of the [`has_many`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) relationship (specifically, the `collection=objects` part).

Since you said you'd like to avoid hitting the database, the only solution I've been able to find is to render to JSON in the same way leesungchul suggested, but specifically excluding the `id` fields:

```
p_json = p.to_json(except: [:id], include: {tags: {except: :id}})
```

If you then do:

```
p2 = Post.new(JSON.parse(p_json))
```

You should get back a fully rendered `Post` object without any DB calls.

This, of course, assumes you don't need those `id` fields. In the event you do...frankly I'm not certain of a better solution other than to rename the `id` fields in the `as_json` method.

**Also note:** With this method, because of the lack of `id` fields, you won't be able to use `p2.tags.count`; it will return zero. You'll have to use `.length` instead.

Comment: I think you mean to say `p_json = p.to_json(except: [:id], includes: {tags: {except: [:id]}})` as the way `p_json` is defined by you will give `syntax error`.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Oops, right. I had the `:` on the wrong side. Thank you! Will update.

Comment: Oops..I meant `p_json = p.to_json(except: [:id], include: {tags: {except: [:id]}})` `include` not `includes`

Comment: Did you mean to call `as_json` here? As, calling `to_json` will give the same error Tag expected...got Hash.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Hmm, nope, both should work. I just did a quick test and it works fine for me with both `as_json` and `to_json`. Did you add the `as_json` override in your model for your test?

Comment: @KirtiThorat Thanks. Heh yeah it's a pretty round-about solution. I wish I knew a better way. Hopefully it works for the OP as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
p2.as_json( :include => :tags )
```

Comment: Did you mean `p.to_json`? That didn't work: `p2 = Post.new( JSON.parse(json) )
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Tag(#60747984) expected, got Hash(#15487524)`

Comment: `as_json` doesn't even output valid JSON! `{"id"=>113,` is invalid because `=>` is not JSON.

Comment: @Chloe you should be able to use `to_json` instead in the same manner, with the includes.

Comment: @PaulRichter I mentioned already that doesn't work when de-serializing it.

Comment: @Chloe Sorry, I was on my phone, didn't see that. Regardless, `as_json` returns a hash, which also has the `to_json` method, so does it not work if you invoke that method on the returned hash?

Comment: @PaulRichter No `p2 = Post.new.from_json p.as_json(include: :tags).to_json` 
`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Tag(#60456516) expected, got Hash(#3166764)`

Answer (score -1):

When you call

```
p2.tags
```

you get correct tags but p2 is not saved in the database yet. This seems the reason for

```
p2.tags.count
```

giving a 0 all the time.
If you actually do something like:

```
p2.id = Post.maximum(:id) + 1
p2.tags #Edit: This needs to be done to fetch the tags mapped to p from the database.
p2.save
p2.tags.count
```

You get the correct count

Comment: Your method would create a duplicate record in database. OP is trying to access existing record, not create another one.

Comment: oh sorry! Now I see what he wants to do... In this case I think something like p2.tags.to_a.count should work, no?

Comment: @AhmedFathy The problem is actually centered around the `has_many` relationship in the JSON / hash. The OP's original problem was that they were not including the association in the `to_json`, hence why `.tags` was returning empty. Now, their problem is that when they attempt to use the JSON as the parameter for `.new`, they receive the error at the bottom of their question. That's where they are at presently.

Comment: @PaulRichter. Yeah, OK... I've actually submitted a patch for this and waiting to see what rails maintainers has to say about it.